# Correct path of jar to load applet with native methods from dll

Tags: dll, applet, java-native-interface, java

I want to load a jar which makes a single call to `System.loadLibrary` and loads a dll inside the system. The jar would contain also all native methods implementation.

Since the applet has a single classloader and calling `System.loadLibrary` twice throws `UnsatisfiedLinkError` I can't put the jar loading with the applet itself (If I do it will throw the exception and consecutive native calls will do nothing).

Aware of this problems the hacky solution would be putting the jar into java classpath so it will be loaded once (ext/folder from JRE).

My question is:
What is the correct move to solve this problem without putting the jar inside java ext folder or creating another classpath entry in the system?

Comment: I find strange you call that `System.loadLibrary` method twice : the usage is to put in a `static` block to have it loaded only once. Beside, are you aware of security limitations regarding applets ?

Comment: But if I reload the page it is loaded again, even with static block. And yes I am aware of the security limitations, the applet works fine if I do put the jar inside jre folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to deploy the natives using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

- Put the natives in the root of a signed Jar per system.  E.G.

  - `native-win.jar`
  - `native-osx.jar`
  - `native-nix.jar`
- Create an extension JNLP that references each Jar in an OS specific `resources` section.
- Reference the extension in the main applet or application JNLP.

JWS could be used to launch free floating frames and applets since 1.2.  More recently an applet can also be deployed using JWS and remain embedded in a web page.